# Defining structure for content in drupal

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I am trying to create a site that will enable users to publish their projecs and enlist other people to join their project.

A user should be able to list a project, specify certain attributes (name,description, etc..).

There are few things i'm having trouble with.

First, by default publishing content is refered to as "content", i dont want a user to "add new content" but rather to "list new project".

Second, a project should have certain attributes, some optional and some mandatory, rather then the default title and body,
users should later be able to filter by these attributes when searching for projects.
is there a way to define the structure of content?.

Third, a user should be able to apply to a project, if he applies, the owner of that projects should receive the appliance, and accepte\reject.
In case he accepts, the users profile should be added a record that he is part of that project.

I am completly new to Drupal, and CMS in general.
My main expertise is with java, and I initially thoght about building the site with a java REST api in the backend and angular js in the frontend, but I have 0 experience with security and dodn't know how to do the user authentication and session management.
So I am currently trying out Drupal.

Is Drupal the right solution?
If so, how should I approach the requirements specified above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal (assuming that you are talking about version 7 since 8 is still in beta) is pretty powerful CMS, with a lot of (free) modules allowing it to expand it's possibilities.

When you are in back-end under Structure -> Content types you can see all available content types defined. There is also link "Add content type" which you can use to define your own. That basically means you can add any fields in any types you want. If you don't see the field type you need there is a big chances that there is a module which adds that field type so you just have to install it. You can also remove body (hide it actually), but title must remain (but you don't have to show it on front-end).
There is a "node reference" field type, but you have to install a module for it: https://www.drupal.org/project/references
So you can create dependencies you like.

And that "add new content" is just a link - you can create your own, set title as you like, just keep the same path. You can also set different theme for (some) admin pages if you want them to look differently. Under Structure -> Menus you can even edit admin menu, add new link and stuff..

Drupal is a bit heavy on resources, because of it's complex structure and database abstraction. For static content just turning on (built in) caches will help, but generally adding some additional caching mechanism won't hurt.